# Launching Sublime Text from git bash causes terminal to be unresponsive until Sublime is closed

Tags: sublimetext3, git-bash

I've set up git bash to be able to launch Sublime Text by adding:

```
alias subl="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"
```

into ~/.bash_profile

The problem is that when I open a project in git bash with:

```
subl .
```

Now, I can't use my git bash terminal until I close sublime text. Is there a better way of setting this up so that the terminal isn't blocked by the subl command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hang is happening because your alias is executing `sublime_text.exe` instead of `subl.exe`.

On Windows, those two executables are different things; the first is the actual application itself, and the second is a small stub application that communicates requests to the running application (launching Sublime as needed) and then terminates.

Since you're executing `sublime_text.exe` here, bash is unhelpfully waiting until you quit Sublime before it returns control back to you. If you modify your alias to execute `subl.exe` instead (it's in the same location) then `subl.exe` will talk to the running Sublime and immediately terminate, so that bash can continue.

Note that this is not the case on all operating systems; on Linux for example `subl` is just an alias for the main Sublime binary. Thus this can catch you unaware if you're used to doing things on other systems.